# Terminal - How to overwrite many lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to overwrite the `hello`. But when a `\n` was printed i can't come back to that line.
So what do applications do which overwrite many lines like the program htop.

```
import sys

print 'hello'
print 'huhu',
print '\r\r\rnooooo\r'
```

Comment: You on linux? If yes `curses`. If no *curses*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) third party module has support for changing the position of the cursor, via the "\x1b[?:?H" command string. You can also clear the screen this way.

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
def put_cursor(x,y):
    print "\x1b[{};{}H".format(y+1,x+1)

def clear():
    print "\x1b[2J"

clear()
put_cursor(0,0)
print "hello"
print "huhu"
#return to first line
put_cursor(0,0)
print "noooooo"
```

The module appears to do this by importing ctypes and invoking `windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition`. See [win32.py, line 58](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/colorama/win32.py#L58).

Answer (score 7):

For Linux and macOS users:

```
import time
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()

stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Hello")

stdscr.refresh()
time.sleep(5)         # deliberate wait, else will automatically delete output
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "huhu")
stdscr.refresh()
```

See [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27865384/674039) for Windows users.

Comment: Don't delete, even if the OP is using Windows. It may be useful for someone in the future.

Comment: and there is no plattform independet-way? Is saw one python-program use `os.system('clear')`

Comment: @user3680510 That again is for linux, *sorry* if you are win user.

Comment: @user3680510 Why don't you try?

Comment: don't have one at my hand :(

Answer (score -3):

Print adds a newline. For this it's better to write directly to stdout.

```
 sys.stdout.write("mystring\r")
```

Comment: I think that the OP wants to update text in previous lines, and from what I know you cannot go back to previous lines with the \r escape sequence.

Comment: The OP wasn't actually very clear about what he wanted.  For updating a single line, like a progress bar, a CR is all that is needed.