# How to fix the '\r' function Windows/Mac OS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an issue where I wish to get rid of some print, but it's ignored entirely and several lines are printed out. I have always used `\r` for these solutions. Is there a way round this scenario? (I'm using Mac OS for now, but guaranteed, will switch over to Windows soon.) @Feodoran told me that the `\r` only really works for Linux computers, which is an issue. The code for this is:

```
print ('virus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter')
time.sleep(2)
for i in range(1):
  sys.stdout.write(str(i)+'\r')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
for i in range(1):
sys.stdout.write(str(i)+'\r')
```

And the output is the following:

```
virus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter
0
virus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter
0
```

I've tried `sys.stdout.write` rather than `print` but nothing seems to have changed. I'm not sure what to do in this situation, but if anyone could give me some tips please do. It's deleting the printed line which entirely does NOT work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `for i in range(1):` only iterates once and is the same as it not being there at all. In what terminal are you invoking your python script (i.e. how it's being displayed can depend on what terminal is in use and under which OS (OS X uses \r for line shifts as you say)

Comment: You are correct actually. But I'm still not clear on how to delete the print now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminal - How to overwrite many lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864992/terminal-how-to-overwrite-many-lines) There is a solution for MacOS, maybe it helps.

Comment: Not quite. It just comes up with a blank screen. The 2nd may work.

Comment: No, invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import sys
sys.stdout.write('virus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter')
time.sleep(2)
for i in range(1):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(str(i))
sys.stdout.write('virus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter')
time.sleep(2)
for i in range(1):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(str(i))
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your problem, there are some ambiguities

Comment: Actually, your solution may work for Windows 10.

Comment: Well, here's the output. `virus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter
0virus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter
0`

Comment: I tried it in my Linux machine, and it refreshes the output, sorry

Comment: Oh... I'm to use Windows in about 9 days or so... any solutions for Mac OSX? (I use a website for all my code, otherwise I can't save my work. However, I do have Python downloaded.)